# How to iterate through elements of an array up until its seventh

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that iterates throughout an array

```
function ($data)
        {
            $path = $data->data->data->clicks;
            foreach ($path as $key => $item){
                if ($key >= 0) {
                $array[] = $item->clicks;
                }     
            }
            return json_encode($array);   
        }
```

I try to make it iterate up until its seventh key, I have written an if statement but I am quite new to this and I don't know how to do this.

If it help the array structure look like this:

```
["data"]=>
  object(stdClass)#212 (3) {
    ["status_code"]=>
    int(200)
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#211 (3) {
      ["days"]=>
      int(30)
      ["total_clicks"]=>
      int(6)
      ["clicks"]=>
      array(30) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#215 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466395200)
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#216 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466308800)
        }
        [2]=>
        object(stdClass)#217 (2) {
          ["clicks"]=>
          int(0)
          ["day_start"]=>
          int(1466222400)
        }
```

Comment: For the first 7 items: `foreach (array_slice($path, 0, 7) as $item){` Don't need the `if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a variable that counts up and break when it's greater than 7

```
$num_loops = 0;
foreach ($path as $key => $item){
    $num_loops++;
    if($num_loops > 7) break;
    if ($key >= 0) {
        $array[] = $item->clicks;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short way by using `array_map` and `array_slice` functions(no loops, no `if` conditions):

```
$path = $data->data->data->clicks;
$clicks = array_map(function($o){
    return $o->clicks; 
}, array_slice($path, 0, 7));
```